# Session has been destroyed at product details page

Tags: magento-1.9, session, debug

From last few days, I have been facing a strange issue at product detail page.

At product details page, **session is changing**.. **Old session has been destroyed at new session is being created**.

Have inspected, checked cookie and found that `frontend`  cookie has been changed at details page.

Have tried some thing

- disable all magento 3rd party extensions
- Checking magento setting delayed with cookie.

Till the issue is persistent at system.

**Some info:**

- using magento CE 1.9.1
- Missing patch:`6482,7405,6788,5994,6285`

So,

**can any one give some idea what is the reason for this section change?**

**and how to debug why the session has been changing?**

Comment: Can you retrieve the old session in files / db?

Comment: no... i did not try it. I have seem that frontend session id has been changes at product page

Comment: I'm curious about what happened to the old session, if it became invalid for some reason

Comment: How long is/was the old session valid? Did you maybe activate some additional session cookie checks such as via, x forwarded for, remote address?!

Comment: @thanks Anna & Sander. can u please give me an idea.If any  code  reset the header request,then session is create again? what your thought?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl, i will check it tomorrow and get back to you.Note : i have copy same code & db to another server but there new session creatation is  happening.It just head cache.let see

Comment: @AnnaVölkl please check my answer;;;

Comment: @SanderMangel, please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue in an extension, which some observer code is encrypted.It is only working on production url.

So that i did not get any issue at stage version.

There, some bad logic use and here session is recreated.

So. beware about the extensions